# ¿Hay alguna forma de mostrar por pantalla un número múltiplo de x de carácteres de un array?

Tags: array, bash, terminal

Tengo un array con 252 veces este carácter: █

Quiero mostrar el array completo por pantalla de forma que al reajustar el tamaño de la ventana de la terminal siempre se muestre un número múltiplo de 3 █ en cada línea, es decir que si, por ejemplo, al hacer mas pequeña la ventana de la terminal sólo caben 50 carácteres en cada línea, pues que muestre 48, 48, 48, 48, 48 y 12 en cada respectiva línea de forma que en todas las líneas haya múltiplos de 3.

Para hacer esto estoy intentando usar $(tput cols) para calcular el ancho de la pantalla y le resto 7 unidades para tener un margen a la derecha de la terminal. Además, mi variable tam_total contiene el número de █ del array, en este caso contiene un 252. La variable r contiene el valor de la línea que se está escribiendo - 1.

Por último, en la última fila de la terminal quiero añadir el valor de $tam_total, que me funciona perfectamente.

```
tamanopantalla=$(tput cols)
let "tam_pantalla_usable=tamanopantalla-7"

for ((r=0;r<${#array[@]};r++)){
    if [[ $r -eq 0 ]]
    then 
        if [[ $tam_total -le $tam_pantalla_usable ]] 
        then
            echo -e "${array[$r]}""T=$tam_total"
        else 
            echo -e "${array[$r]}"
        fi
    else
        let "ult_linea=r+1"
        if [[ $tam_total -ge $tam_pantalla_usable ]] && [[ $ult_linea = ${#array[@]} ]]
        then
            echo -e "${array[$r]}""T=$tam_total"
        else 
            echo -e "${array[$r]}"
        fi
    fi
}
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es si existe alguna forma fácil de mostrar múltiplos de 3 █ en todas mis líneas.

Answer (score 0):

Existe la función `mod` la cual retorna el resto de la división de un numero por otro con lo cual puedes saber su un numero es múltiplo de n.

```
echo $((n % 3))
```

si el resultado es = 0 , entonces implica que n es múltiplo de 3 ya que no hay resto en su división y si el resultado <> 0, entonces significa que hay un resto y por lo tanto n no es multiplo de 3, lo único que queda es incorporarlo en tu procedimiento.